# Android GO: display over apps work around

Tags: android

I recently wrote an app that requerd display over other apps. When I tried installing it on my Android phone the system responds that the display over apps feature has been disabled. But true caller app, one of the apps I have on my phone displays over other apps without having requested the permission. This shows that there's a walk around for display over other apps on Android go. Do any one know about walk around please.

Comment: answer is [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246036/how-can-i-enable-display-over-other-apps-in-nokia-1-4-when-feature-is-disabled)